# Gridjs pagination and sort with server side parameters

Tags: javascript, gridjs

i use [gridsjs](https://gridjs.io/) sort and paginaton server side config, when i use for pagination its work perfectly, but for sorting the params not work properly like this http://scrum.test/api/customers&sort_by=id&sort=DESC?page=1 when the correct one like this http://scrum.test/api/customers/?sort_by=id&sort=ASC&page=1, and this is my code.

```js
let tableCustomer = $('#table-customer').Grid({
        columns: [
            'ID',
            'Name',
            'Email'
        ],
        search: true,
        pagination: {
            enabled: true,
            limit: 20,
            server: {
                url: (prev, page, limit) =>  {
                    return `${prev}?page=${(page+1)}`
                }
            }
        },
        sort : {
            server: {
                url: (prev, columns) => {
                    console.log('sprt', prev);
                    if (!columns.length) return prev;
                    const col = columns[0];
                    const dir = col.direction === 1 ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
                    let colName = ['id', 'name', 'email'][col.index];
                    
                    return `${prev}&sort_by=${colName}&sort=${dir}`;
                }
            }
        },
        
        server : {
            url: BASE_URL + 'api/customers',
            then: response => response.data.map(customer => [ customer.id, customer.name, customer.email]),
            total: response => response.total
        },
        
        
    });
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I believe there is a bug in Grid.JS that is calling sort.server.url too many times, but in your case, change the {prev}&sort_by to {prev}?sort_by and you'll at least get a value endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

As you did it with pagination, it is necessary to do it with sorting.
To **ENABLE** the sorting plugin. Sort has two config objects:

**Generic config**: to enable sort for all columns, enable multi column sort, server-side integration, etc.
**Column specific config**: to enable sort on a specific column, to set custom comparator function, etc.

#### Generic sort config:

- `optional`
- Type: `boolean` or `GenericSortConfig`
- Example: [Sorting](https://gridjs.io/docs/examples/sorting)

#### Column specific sort config

- `optional`
- Type: `boolean` or `SortConfig`
- Example: [Custom sort](https://gridjs.io/docs/examples/custom-sort)

`SortConfig` type has the following properties:

- enabled - to enable/disable pagination -  boolean
- compare `optional` -  custom comparator function - `Comparator<TCell>`

So, following the official documentation above, this piece of code would

```js
        sort : {
            server: {
                url: (prev, columns) => {
                    console.log('sprt', prev);
                    if (!columns.length) return prev;
                    const col = columns[0];
                    const dir = col.direction === 1 ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
                    let colName = ['id', 'name', 'email'][col.index];
                    
                    return `${prev}&sort_by=${colName}&sort=${dir}`;
                }
            }
        },
```

It should look something like this:

```js
        sort: {
          enabled: true,
          multiColumn: true,
          server: {
            url: (prev, columns) => {
              const columnIds = ['id', 'name', 'email'];
              const sort = columns.map(col => (col.direction === 1 ? '+' : '-') + columnIds[col.index]);
              return updateUrl(prev, {sort});
            },
          },
        },
```

`updateURL`:

```js
      const updateUrl = (prev, query) => {
        return prev + (prev.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?') + new URLSearchParams(query).toString();
      };
```